# Format of com.apple.loginitems.plist in os x 10.8

Tags: objective-c, macos

What is format of ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginitems.plist in os x 10.8?
I develop kid control application and want to examine different user account startup item list.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's a [binary property list](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/plist.5.html).  You can use [`plutil(1)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/plist.5.html) to convert it to XML if you want to edit it as text.  For binary editing, use the format described in [`CFBinaryPList.c`](http://opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-550/CFBinaryPList.c).

Answer (score 0):

Usually (maybe always?) you can call

`[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[@"~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginitems.plist" stringByStandardizingPath]]`

and load a dictionary directly from the plist file. That is, of course, assuming you are doing this from a Cocoa app.